# imageItem save function doesn't save the image with the scale applied to it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

The imageItem class save function in the pyqtgraph library indicates that when the 2D image is saved, it retains the scale/color for the visible range as shown in the [documentation](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/ImageItem.html#ImageItem.save). When I used it before, it worked. But now it doesn't. I'm not sure if it is a bug or not.

Here is a sample code I used for testing.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Demonstrates very basic use of ImageItem to display image data inside a PlotItem.
"""

## Add path to library (just for examples; you do not need this)
# import initExample

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5.QtCore import  QRectF

from matplotlib.pyplot import imread

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

## Create window with GraphicsView widget
win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
win.show()  ## show widget alone in its own window
win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: ImageItem')
view = win.addPlot()

## lock the aspect ratio so pixels are always square
view.setAspectLocked(True)

## Create image item
img = pg.ImageItem(border='w')
view.addItem(img)

## Set initial view bounds
# view.setRange(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 600, 600))

## Create random image
getFileName = "Path_to_load_image"
data = imread(getFileName)
img.setImage(data)

height = data.shape[1] 
width = data.shape[0]

xpos = 0.5
ypos = 1.5
img.setRect(QRectF(0, 0,xpos*width,ypos*height))

view.autoRange(items=[img])

saveFileName = "path_to_save"
img.save(saveFileName)

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: Could you explain your sentence better: *When I used it before, it worked. But now it doesn't*, have you updated the pyqtgraph version after it worked correctly? What version of pyqtgraph do you use?

Comment: @eyllanesc The pyqtgraph version I'm using is 0.11.0. I haven't upgraded the version. Using the same version couple of months ago worked just find. But now, the save function won't save an image with the scale applied to it.